# SQLite - select the newest row with a certain field value

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have an SQLite question which essentially boils down to the following problem.

```
id | key | data
1  |   A |  x
2  |   A |  x
3  |   B |  x
4  |   B |  x
5  |   A |  x
6  |   A |  x
```

New data is appended to the end of the table with an auto-incremented id.

Now, I want to create a query which returns the latest row for each key, like this:

```
id | key | data
4  |   B |  x
6  |   A |  x
```

I've tried some different queries but I have been unsuccessful. How do you select only the latest rows for each "key" value in the table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use this SQL-Query:

```
select * from tbl where id in (select max(id) from tbl group by key);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
    JOIN 
        ( SELECT MAX(id) AS maxid
          FROM mytable
          GROUP BY "key"
        ) AS grp
      ON grp.maxid = mytable.id
```

Side note: it's best not to use reserved words like `key`as identifiers (for tables, fields. etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You could split the main task into two subroutine.

You could move with the approach first retrieve all **id/key** value then get the **id** for the latest value of `A` and `B` keys,

Now you could easly write a query to get latest value for `A` and `B` because you have value of **id's** for both `A` and `B` keys.

Answer (score 0):

Without nested SELECTs, or JOINs but only if the field determining "newest" is primary key (e.g. autoincrement):

```
  SELECT * FROM table GROUP BY key DESC;
```